# Migrate from semantic-ui to fomantic-ui?

Tags: node.js, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

Any recommendations on how to migrate an existing Node project from using Semantic-UI to Fomantic-UI? I know Fomantic-UI is a fork of Semantic-UI and backward compatible, so I'm wondering if I can simply run:

- npm remove semantic-ui
- npm install fomantic-ui

Would I need do make any updates to the existing /semantic directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm uninstall package_name`

this is the npm code to uninstall or remove a package

to install it is:

`npm install package_name`

in your case it will be

`npm uninstall semantic-ui`

`npm install fomantic-ui`

Comment: That easy? I don't have to update anything else like pre-existing templates, scripts or anything? It sounds easy, so I'm just verifying.

Comment: you have used npm remove instead of npm uninstall for removing we use npm uninstall instead of npm remove

Comment: i dont know much about fomantic-ui, you must see the docs of fomantic ui, if you uninstall semantic-ui the templates and html and pre existing code wont work you need to make changes based on fomantic ui

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you Syed!